# Many BackgroundWorker instances vs one with Tasks and WorkerReportsProgress

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, backgroundworker

I have many-tables GUI application. Each table filled with assistance of its own BackgroundWorker instance. But now I need render a table that rows are gotten from different slow remote sources. So each its row also should be shown parallel as soon as it be received.

I see two way:

- instead of BackgroundWorker for the table to create the instance per
  row;
- continue use BackgroundWorker (for interactions with UI) but in
  DoWorkEventHandler perform Parallel.ForEach requests for source in
  collection with ProgressChanged call after its response.

Which is more correct?

Comment: what you  means by 'different slow remote sources' are you using WCF Remoting  or what ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. They just spend a long time for response.

Answer (score 0):

assuming it's like my case i have source that are mostly third party and no control over and split around different format (web service, WCF, Local Unmanaged DLL,.Net DLL, Java Service and Excel) just to fill a single list.

Anyhow in my case i used 7 workers.
the first one list all the source and nowaday i have 40-ish sources.

then the worker start up to 6 other workers with 1 source each and update progress async. once one worker finish the main worker start a new one with the next of the list and so on.

I noticed that over 6 i slow performance in my case but that depend on your architecture and type of source. if i had less source accessed by the web i could increase that but bandwidth slows down.